# ¿Como puedo graficar los datos de la tabla que se imprime en forma dinamica utilizando la libreria Chart.js?

Tags: php, html, chart.js

Necesito graficar los resultados de una encuesta, en el siguiente archivo html llamo a la funcion que imprime una tabla.

```
 <?php $Encuesta->mostrarResultadosDeEncuesta(1); ?>
```

Dicha funcion imprime los datos de la siguiente manera: En el encabezado de la tabla se imprime la pregunta y en el cuerpo de la tabla se imprimen las respuestas y los votos de cada respuesta.

public function imprimirResultadosDeEncuesta(string $id_tabla, string $encabezado_tabla, string $id_boton_descarga, string $id_canvas, array $respuestas, array $votos)
{

```
?>
<div class="container">

  <div class="row justify-content-center">

    <div class="col-6">
  
      <table class="table text-center table-striped table-hover" id="<?php echo $id_tabla; ?>">

        <thead>
      
          <tr>  

           <th><?php echo $encabezado_tabla; ?></th>

           </tr> 

        </thead>

        <tbody>

          <?php 

          for($i = 0; $i < count($respuestas); $i++)
          {

          ?>

          <tr>
        
            <td><?php echo $respuestas[$i]; ?></td>

            <td><?php echo $votos[$i]; ?></td>

          </tr>

          <?php
          }//fin bucle for

          ?>
      
        </tbody>
    
      </table>

    </div><!-- <div class="col-12"> -->

  </div><!-- <div class="row"> -->
```

En conjunto con la tabla, llamo a la funcion de JavaScript que recibe como parametro:
-El titulo del grafico,
-El id de la tabla,
-El id del canvas,
-Las respuestas que se imprimiran en el eje X y
-Los votos que se imprimirán en el eje Y

CODIGO :

```
<canvas id="<?php echo $id_canvas;  ?>" >

  <script>graficar('<?php echo $encabezado_tabla; ?>','<?php echo $id_tabla; ?>','<?php echo $id_canvas; ?>',0,1)</script>    

</canvas>
```

El problema es que solo aparece el fondo del grafico y no se muestran las barras.

Adjunto el codigo JavaScript que utilizo para realizar el grafico

```
    function graficar(titulo_grafico, nombre_tabla, id_canvas, indice_eje_x, indice_eje_y){
const tabla = document.getElementById(nombre_tabla)   /* tabla4 */
let provincias = []
let vim = []

tabla.childNodes[indice_eje_x].childNodes.forEach(element => {

    if(element.cells != null)
    {
        provincias.push(element.cells[indice_eje_x].textContent)
        vim.push(element.cells[indice_eje_y].textContent.replace('%','').replace(',','.'))
    }
    
    
});


const ctx = document.getElementById(id_canvas).getContext('2d');

    // Podemos tener varios conjuntos de datos. Comencemos con uno
    const datos = {
        label: titulo_grafico,
        // Pasar los datos igualmente desde PHP
        data: vim, // <- Aquí estamos pasando el valor traído usando AJAX
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)', // Color de fondo
        borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)', // Color del borde
        borderWidth: 1, // Ancho del borde

        
    };
    
    const nuevoGrafico = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar', // Tipo de gráfica
        data: {
            labels: provincias,
            datasets: [
                datos,
                // Aquí más datos...
            ]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }],
            },
        }
    })

}
```